# 'bool' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to revise my code and make it object-oriented, but now it fails to work. Whenever I call `if snake.rect.colliderect(food.rect)`, it returns `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'rect'`. Here is the rest of my code if that helps.

```
import pygame,sys,random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

RES = (500,500)

rectangle_height = 20
rectangle_width = 20

GREEN = (0,255,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
win = pygame.display.set_mode(RES)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

class Snake():
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((rectangle_width,rectangle_height))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed = 20  
        self.move = (0,0)

class Food():
    def __init__(self,color,width,height):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((rectangle_width,rectangle_height))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(20,500,20) 
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(20,500,20) 

        self.state = True

def event_loop(snake,food):
    while True:
        win.fill(BLACK)

        # for x in range(0,win_width,20):
        #     pygame.draw.line(win,WHITE,(x,0),(x,500))

        # for y in range(0,win_height,20):
        #     pygame.draw.line(win,WHITE,(0,y),(500,y))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    snake.move = (snake.speed,0)
                elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                    snake.move = (-snake.speed,0)
                elif event.key == K_UP:
                    snake.move = (0,-snake.speed)
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    snake.move = (0,snake.speed)

        if snake.rect.colliderect(food.rect):
            food.state = False

        if food.state:
            win.blit(food.image,food.rect)
        else:
            food.rect.x = random.randrange(20,500,20) 
            food.rect.y = random.randrange(20,500,20) 
            win.blit(food.image,food.rect)
            food = True

        win.blit(snake.image,snake.rect)
        snake.rect.move_ip(snake.move)
        snake.rect.clamp_ip(win.get_rect())

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(5)

snake = Snake(GREEN,rectangle_width,rectangle_height)
food = Food(RED,rectangle_width,rectangle_height)
event_loop(snake,food)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are assigning a value to `food` twice. The first time is that at file level:

```
food = Food(RED,rectangle_width,rectangle_height)
```

This is fine, and your code would probably work, if it weren't for the second time you're setting `food`, in your `event_loop`:

```
food = True
```

After that call, food is a boolean, and hence the error you're getting, which is telling you that bools don't have a `rect` property.

Remove that second assignment, and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for asking a question on a stupid typo that I missed. I changed it to "food.state = True" and it worked.